# How to display submenu links in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

I am attempting to create a sidebar menu in React and I want to know what is the best way to display submenu links/items based on the category? For example, I have 3 categories: "action", "comedy", & "horror." Each of these would have submenu items, i.e. - "action" would have "Die Hard", "Ong Bak", and "John Wick."

Example:

```
Menu

Action
    Die Hard
    Ong Bak
    John Wick

Comedy
    Friday
    Old School
    This is the End

Horror
    Exorcist
    Midsomar
    Hereditary
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    type: 'action',
    key: 'diehard',
    name: 'Die Hard',
    
  },
  {
    type: 'action',
    key: 'ong-bak',
    name: 'OngBak'
  },
  {
    type: 'action',
    key: 'johnwick',
    name: 'JohnWick'
  },
  {
    type: 'comedy',
    key: 'friday',
    name: 'Friday'
  },
  {
    type: 'comedy',
    key: 'old-school',
    name: 'OldSchool'
  },
  {
    type: 'comedy',
    key: 'this-is-the-end',
    name: 'ThisistheEnd',
  }
]
```

Currently, the way I have it set up won't display it the way I want to. But I welcome any suggestions

```
import React from 'react';
import {Menu} from './menu/menu';
import {SubMenu} from './menu/submenu';
import {SubMenuItem} from './menu/submenuitem';

export function SideMenu({ routes }) {
    return (
        <SideBar>
            <Menu>
                {routes.map((route, index) => {
                    if (route.type === 'action') {
                        return (
                            <SubMenuItem 
                                type={route.type} 
                                key={route.key} 
                                name={route.name} 
                                onClick={onClickHandler} 
                            />
                        );
                    }
                })}
            </Menu>
        </SideBar>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, here is how I done this. I have done this before by creating a  json data as the following example. Then, you can use js array map function to iterate each object and check whether the object has a key for subitem then render another style or code block accordingly. If your menu items all have subitem, maybe you may not have to do nested map function in this case. Note that the Submenu component will render the parent item then only render its children(subitem). I am using react-bootstrap to help me do the stylling.

Sample output:

```
All Movies
Action 
 Die Hard
 Ong Bak
 John Wick
Comedy 
 Friday
 Old School
```

Example of the JSON menu data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "All Movies",
    "path": "/movie/all",
    "icon": "fa-movie"
  },
  {
    "name": "Action",
    "path": "#",
    "icon": "fa-movie",
    "subitem": [
      {
        "name": "Die Hard",
        "path": "/movie/Die-Hard",
        "icon": "fa-movie"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ong Bak",
        "path": "/movie/Ong-Bak",
        "icon": "fa-movie"
      },
      {
        "name": "John Wick",
        "path": "/movie/John-Wick",
        "icon": "fa-movie"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Comedy",
    "path": "#",
    "icon": "fa-movie",
    "subitem": [
      {
        "name": "Friday",
        "path": "/movie/Friday",
        "icon": "fa-movie"
      },
      {
        "name": "Old School",
        "path": "/movie/Old-School",
        "icon": "fa-movie"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Example in react:

The main Sidebar component

```
<div className="wrapper">
            <div className="sidebar-body">
              <Nav className="sidebar-nav d-flex align-items-end flex-column">
                {menuItems.map((navItem) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={navItem.name} className="nav-item submenu-control">
                      {"subitem" in navItem ? (
                        // Main Nav-Links(Parent) details passed as props
                        <Submenu
                          sidebarExpand={sidebarExpand}
                          navText={navItem.name}
                          navIcon={navItem.icon}
                        >
                          <Nav className="sidebar-nav">
                            {navItem.subitem.map((subitem) => {
                              return (
                                <div key={subitem.name} className="nav-item">
                                  <Link
                                    className="nav-link d-flex flex-row"
                                    to={subitem.path}
                                    onClick={this.closeAll}
                                  >
                                    <i
                                      className={`fas ${subitem.icon} fa-2x fa-fw`}
                                    ></i>
                                    <span className="link-text">
                                      {subitem.name}
                                    </span>
                                  </Link>
                                </div>
                              );
                            })}
                          </Nav>
                        </Submenu>
                      ) : (
                        <Link
                          onClick={this.closeAll}
                          className="nav-link d-flex flex-row"
                          to={navItem.path}
                        >
                          <i className={`fas ${navItem.icon} fa-2x fa-fw`}></i>
                          <span className="link-text">{navItem.name}</span>
                        </Link>
                      )}
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </Nav>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The Submenu Component

```
return (
      <>
        <div className="nav-link d-flex flex-row">
          <i className={`fas ${this.props.navIcon} fa-2x fa-fw`}></i>
          <span className="link-text">{this.props.navText}</span>
          <i className="ml-auto fas fa-caret-right fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card>{this.props.children}</Card>
        </div>
      </>
    );
```

Here is another great example on geeksforgeeks

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-responsive-sidebar-with-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs/

Comment: This is a great start, but problem is I just found out I have a JSON that we're using for the router and I have no ability to change it :/